# Converting JSON into Swift objects using Codable

Tags: swift4, codable, json-api

I saw somewhere on StackOverflow there was a website that converted your JSON API into Struct and Codable protocols and for the life of me, I can't find it. I did not bookmark it, unfortunately.  Any help would be appreciated in finding this site.

Comment: I know jsoneditoronline that is not that site I was looking for.  It’s another one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try **[Quicktype](https://quicktype.io/)**. this web app allows you to convert JSON in Swift Type or any language such as Go, Dart, Java, C++, RUBY, etc.

https://app.quicktype.io/

Answer (score 0):

just paste your json code in there and see the result:
[jsoneditoronline](http://jsoneditoronline.org)

Comment: I think I have found it. It’s called Quicktype. I’ve closed my Mac so will check later.

Comment: @AltBrian I check Quicktype. it's really good site. thank you